# How to prevent an object from being created redundantly in a many-to-many relationship with a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an API with Rails for a forum/chatroom. I have three models:

```
class User < Application record
  has_many messages
  has_many :forums, through: :messages

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :forum
end

class Forum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
  has_many :users, through: :messages
end
```

The idea is the user who is logged in can be a part of multiple different forums, and create a message in that specific forum.

When the user creates a new message, it's also creating a new forum every time. So, the same user1 posts in the "GENERAL" forum multiple times resulting in:

```
User1.forums=["GENERAL","GENERAL","GENERAL"]
```

This is breaking my front end.

Is there a way to set-up the associations in a way that if the user already has this forum not to add the same one to its list of forums?

Comment: You could check that on method create and skip if already some forum created by user. Or you can do some validations please check this page for more info and try here to find solution for your case: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read about the differences between an [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html) and a [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). A Set will automatically do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `distinct` scope on the association:

```
has_many :forums, -> { distinct }, through: :messages
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many-distinct

EDIT: if your code is actually creating multiple forums it won't help since the forums won't be the same, if that's your case then show your form and your controller, if you are creating forums on each created message you have another problem

Comment: Thank you! yes this was the solution, it wasnt creating an additional forum. it just kept adding an entry for the same forum for user.forums , for each additional message that was created. This helped.